# How to get last row with inner join and group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with one SQL query.

So I have two tables:
Animelist + Animeepisode and I would like to get last 8 rows from animelist joined with last animeepisodes. So far I have something like this:

```
 SELECT MAX(a.id) AS id, a.id_anime AS id_anime, a.nazev AS nazev, b.nazev AS nazev_anime, b.id AS idd 
 FROM animedily AS a 
 INNER JOIN animelist AS b ON a.id_anime = b.id 
 GROUP BY b.id 
 ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 0,8
```

Which give me LAST anime from animelist (exactly what I need :-)), but every first episode from animeepisodes(I need last :-p)

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: some example maybe ? example and wished result

Comment: You will have to group your `AnimeEpisodes` and then join them, otherwise you will end up with the 1st row which is relevant to a particular `ID` from the `Animelist tbl`

Comment: Well my SQL is little bit rusty, would you help me with this query? If you need more info or TBLS dump just say so.